# Updating only certain fields on a database row

Tags: sql, mysql, pdo

I have data that I want to insert in a database.  Sometime a piece of data is already in the database, so I just want to update the fields that changed.

For example, if I insert these rows one after the other:

> ```
> id | field1 | field2 | field3
> 1  | foo    | NULL   | bar
> 1  | baz    | hello  | NULL
> ```

I want to end up with:

> ```
> id | field1 | field2 | field3
> 1  | baz    | hello  | bar
> ```

I use this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO `device` (`device_id`, `model`, `manufacturer`, `version`, `vendor_id`, `osd_name`)
VALUES (....) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `version` = IFNULL(VALUES(`version`), `version`), `vendor_id` = IFNULL(VALUES(`vendor_id`), `vendor_id`), `osd_name` = IFNULL(VALUES(`osd_name`), `osd_name`)
```

Note that not all fields have to be updated. Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is.

What you are asking for is known as `UPSERT` - a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. Some databases support `UPSERT` intrinsically, but some don't. A quick search for "MySQL UPSERT" suggests that MySQL does not support an `UPSERT` keyword or the concept directly. However, as you discovered, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` construct will simulate it.

That seems the best way to do it in MySQL. (In SQL Server you would probably use `MERGE`.)